# Move object from a RecyclerView to another RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I'm currently making a booking app for some football fields. I have two recycler views: active bookings and cancelled bookings. I also have a custom recycler view adapter. Both of the recycler views use the same adapter.

What I want to do: if I click on a button inside my active bookings recycler view, I want to remove the booking from the active bookings and put it into my cancelled bookings. I'm gonna leave my custom adapter with the mention that I use Firebase in order to get my booking status (active or cancelled).

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapterRezervare extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapterRezervare.RecycleViewHolder> {
    private List<Rezervare> rezervari;
    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private String numeUtilizator;
    private String status;

    private Rezervare rezervare = new Rezervare();

    private DatabaseReference reff;

    public RecyclerViewAdapterRezervare(List<Rezervare> rezervari, Context context, String numeUtilizator) {
        this.rezervari = rezervari;
        this.context = context;
        this.numeUtilizator = numeUtilizator;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecycleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rezervari_layout, parent, false);
        return new RecycleViewHolder(view);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecycleViewHolder holder, int position) {
        rezervare = rezervari.get(position);

        reff = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();


        List<String> listaOre = rezervare.getOre();
        Map<String, Object> mapOre = new HashMap<>();
        for(String ora : listaOre){
            mapOre.put(ora, false);
        }

        // this will return the status ("activa" is the booking is active, or "anulata" is it's cancelled)
        getStatus(rezervare, new StatusCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCallback(String value) {
                status = value;

                holder.btn_anuleaza.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Log.v("status", status);
                        new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext()).setTitle("Anulare rezervare").setMessage("Sunteti sigur ca doriti anularea rezervarii?")
                            .setPositiveButton(R.string.da, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                              
// if the cancel button is clicked, i update my database so the status of the booking will be "anulata" - cancelled                                reff.child("Users").child(numeUtilizator).child("rezervari").child(rezervare.getData()).child(rezervare.getNumeTeren()).child("status").setValue("anulata");
                                reff.child("Rezervari").child(rezervare.getData()).child("Fotbal").child(rezervare.getNumeTeren()).updateChildren(mapOre);
                                rezervare.setEsteAnulata(false);
                                Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Anulare cu succes!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            }
                        }).setNegativeButton(R.string.nu, null).show();

                    }
                });

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return rezervari.size();
    }


    // i have updated my code with the delete and insert a booking
    public void stergeRezervare(int position){
        rezervari.remove(position);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void adaugaRezervare(Rezervare rezervare){
        rezervari.add(rezervare);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

This is the function that gets me the bookings from firebase
i have 3 separate lists for active bookings, cancelled and past bookings.

```
public interface RezervariListCallback {
        void onCallback(List<Rezervare> rezervariActuale, List<Rezervare> rezervariTrecute, List<Rezervare> rezervariAnulate);
    }

    public void getRezervari(String nume, RezervariListCallback myCallback){
        reff.child("Users").child(nume).child("rezervari").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot data : snapshot.getChildren()){
                    String dataRezervare = data.getKey();
                    dateRezervari.add(dataRezervare);

                    reff.child("Users").child(nume).child("rezervari").child(dataRezervare).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                       @Override
                       public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                            for(DataSnapshot data : snapshot.getChildren()){
                                String numeTeren = data.getKey();

                                reff.child("Users").child(nume).child("rezervari").child(dataRezervare).child(numeTeren).child("ore").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                                        List<String> ore = new ArrayList<>();
                                        for(DataSnapshot data : snapshot.getChildren()){
                                            String ora = data.getKey();
                                            ore.add(ora);
                                        }

                                        getAdresa(nume, dataRezervare, numeTeren, new AdresaCallback() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onCallbackAdresa(String value) {
                                                Rezervare rezervare = new Rezervare(numeTeren, ore, dataRezervare, value);
                                                String dataAzi = getDataAzi();

                                                reff.child("Users").child(nume).child("rezervari").child(dataRezervare).child(numeTeren).child("status").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                                                    @Override
                                                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                                                        String status = (String) snapshot.getValue();

                                                        if(comparaData(dataAzi, rezervare.getData())){
                                                            if(status.equals("activa")){
                                                                rezervariActive.add(rezervare);
                                                            } else {
                                                                rezervariAnulate.add(rezervare);
                                                            }
                                                        } else {
                                                            rezervariTrecute.add(rezervare);
                                                        }

                                                        myCallback.onCallback(rezervariActive, rezervariTrecute, rezervariAnulate);
                                                    }

                                                    @Override
                                                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                                                    }
                                                });
                                            }
                                        });


                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                                    }
                                });
                            }
                       }

                       @Override
                       public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                       }
                    });
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }
```

and this is where i set the adapters

```
 public void updateRezervari(View view, RecyclerView activeBookingsRecycler, RecyclerView pastBookingsRecycler, RecyclerView cancelledBookingsRecycler){
        AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                getRezervari(numeUtilizator, new RezervariListCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCallback(List<Rezervare> rezervariActuale, List<Rezervare> rezervariTrecute, List<Rezervare> rezervariAnulate) {
                        if(rezervariActuale.size()>0){
                            tvFaraRezervariActive.setEnabled(false);
                            tvFaraRezervariAnulate.setEnabled(false);
                            tvFaraRezervariTrecute.setEnabled(false);
                        }

                        Log.v("rezAc", rezervariActuale.toString());
                        Log.v("rezTr", rezervariTrecute.toString());

                        RecyclerViewAdapterRezervare adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapterRezervare(rezervariActuale, view.getContext(), numeUtilizator);
                        activeBookingsRecycler.setAdapter(adapter);
                        adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapterRezervare(rezervariTrecute, view.getContext(), numeUtilizator);
                        pastBookingsRecycler.setAdapter(adapter);
                        adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapterRezervare(rezervariAnulate, view.getContext(), numeUtilizator);
                        cancelledBookingsRecycler.setAdapter(adapter);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

Can you give me a few tips on how to move from one recycler view to another? Thank you!

Comment: `Can you give me a few tips on how to move from one recycler view to another?` recyclerviews are controlled by adapters. remove from the one adapter, add to the other one, notify the adapters that the data has changed

Comment: There's much going on in your code, so it's hard to debug all those lines of code. Will it be helpful an answer which will cover another (personal) approach that will help you achieve the same thing? Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo i have edited my post and i hope it's more easier to follow now.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Firebase to fetch status of a booking, you can update the status to cancelled in your firebase database and then you will get a callback from your firebase listener where you can update your arraylists and call notifyDataSetChanged().

Comment: i don't really know how to do that. i do have a code that retrieves the bookings everytime i cancel a booking but it takes to long and it doesn't get me where i want. I've made a video: https://streamable.com/flvjxo and it shows how it works. basically when i cancel a booking it gets me to the football fields fragment and i don't want that. 
I can delete from the active bookings but i don't know how to add to the cancelled bookings so it has immediate effect.

Comment: Can you share your code where you call these add and remove booking method in adapter class?

Comment: Well the thing is i don't call the methods because i don't know where to call them. i have the "profile" fragment in which i have the recyclerviews and inside the fragment i call the method to get me the bookings from firebase, and then i simply set each adapter with the corresponding list of bookings. I have update my post with the methods to set the adapters, and to get me the firebase bookings.